# Export Fusion Table to text file

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a large amount of data in a Google fusion table. How can I export it to a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on File:Download.

That will download the data as a .csv (comma separated value) file which is text (but can also be imported into most spreadsheets).